# How to handle Times in relation to Bookings

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I'm developing a booking system where by certain users can book an Activity for a specific date and time (these times are Activity specific). The system needs to check if that Activity is available at this time (There may be a class being held at that time, for example).

How would I represent the date/times that an Activity can be booked in a Database schema?

Example:

```
Activity - Swimming
Available times:
Monday : 9am - 5pm
Tuesday : 9am - 12pm
Wednesday : 9am - 4pm
Thursday : 10am - 3pm
Friday : 9am - 5pm
```

If I have a record in my Activity table for the Swimming activity. Which holds details such as the description, cost etc how would I store this schedule in a field?

Thanks.

Comment: Are times available as hours? For example can an activity only be book Wed. 9:00-10:00 or can it be booked for a random interval? Is  there a set number of people per interval?

Comment: An activity can be booked in quarterly periods. So an hour and a half, and hour and 15 minutes etc. There's a field in the Activity table which represents the capacity of the activity. So yes, there is a limit on how many people can be booked onto the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you have a separate table for schedules with an [int](http://goo.gl/atOHv) `ScheduleID` primary key, [int](http://goo.gl/atOHv) `ActivityID` foreign key, [datetime](http://goo.gl/GhpbN) `StartTime`, [time](http://goo.gl/po36D) `Interval` and any other columns it needs.

Then, when checking to see if a new activity conflicts with a previously scheduled one, you can use LINQ to SQL:

```
bool conflict = (from i in db.Schedules
                 where potential.StartTime > i.StartTime
                 && potential.StartTime < i.StartTime.Add(i.Interval)
                 select i).Count() > 0;
```

**Disclaimer:** Not 100% sure the DataContext will make it work this way.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. So, if I'm interpreting correctly, there'll be 5 records corresponding to each Activity (one for each day of the week)? With your LINQ query, I'd probably need to add an extra WHERE clause to filter the schedule for a particular Activity right?

Comment: No, this is a little more open than that. The `Activity` could more accurately be called an `ActivityType` (e.g., swimming, bowling, etc.). Instead of storing schedules in 5-7 columns in the `Activity` table, there would simply be a bunch of schedules that correspond to certain time periods and a certain type of activity. To reduce repetition in the table, you could add a [time](http://goo.gl/po36D) `RecurringFrequency` to the Schedule table and set it to weekly, biweekly, etc.

Comment: To filter for a specific `ActivityType`, you could do `var footballActivities = from i in db.Schedules where i.ActivityType.Name == "football" select i;`, which will grab all the football schedules. That would mean that the `ActivityType` table would have a primary key [int](http://goo.gl/atOHv) `ActivityID`, [varchar(20)](http://goo.gl/GmM6U) `Name`, [varchar(160)](http://goo.gl/GmM6U) `Description` and any other columns it might need.

Comment: For a very robust example of LINQ to SQL's power, consider this query: `var filtered = from i in db.Schedules where i.User.Username == "Nick" && i.ActivityType.Name == "football" && i.StartTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && i.Interval.TotalHours < 1 select i;`, which grabs all schedules scheduled by some user Nick, where he's playing football on a Monday for less than an hour. **Note:** I may be wrong in remembering how the `DataContext` handles the conversion from tables to .NET objects. For example, `i.User.Username` may be `i.UserID.Username`. Fortunately, Intellisense will let you know.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. I think I've got it now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would represent this as a start and end date with a time function.

Here is your code

```
public enum ActivityType
{
    Swimming = 1,
    Biking = 2,
    Basketball = 3,
    Soccer = 4
}

public class Booking
{
    public DateTime BookingStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime BookingEnd { get; set; }

    public Activity Activity { get; set; }

    public bool ValidateBooking()
    {
        // put logic here to ensure that the booking times fall within the activity start and end time
        return true;
    }
}

public class Activity
{
    public ActivityType ActivityType { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivityStartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivityEndTime { get; set; }
}
```

In your database you would have a table that contains this information.

Booking Table

```
ID int
ActivityID int (foreign key to Activty.ID)
BookingStart DateTime
BookingEnd DateTime
```

Activity Tables

```
ID int
ActivityType int
ActivityStartTime DateTime
ActivityEndTime DateTime
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This is a good approach for handling bookings, but it's the Activity Schedule im having problems with. That is, the time period for each day, where the activity is available.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your activities occur in 15 minute intervals, you may find a calendar table relevant, this would also allow you exclude closed days. Your calendar could contain a date and quarter hour rows for each activity. A separate table would contain the calendar id and the client id, allowing you to get a count and limit the number of bookings per slot according to the rules.